# Clearing Symfony cache for another application

Tags: php, caching, symfony1

I would like to clear my frontend application's cache from an action in my backend application.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the proper way to do this in symfony 1.2 is as follows:

```
sfContext::switchTo('frontend'); //switch to the environment you wish to clear
sfContext::getInstance()->getViewCacheManager()->getCache()->clean(sfCache::ALL);
sfContext::switchTo('backend'); //switch back to the environment you started from
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. It removes all cached files from the given directory:

```
$cache_dir = sfConfig::get('sf_cache_dir').'/'.$app.'/'.$env.'/';

$cache = new sfFileCache(array('cache_dir' => $cache_dir));
$cache->clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for clearing one cache item (one page):

```
sfContext::switchTo('frontend');
sfContext::getInstance()->getViewCacheManager()->remove("module/action?&param1=value1&param2=value2","THE-DOMAIN-OF-YOUR-FRONTEND-APPLICATION-IF-U-USE-IT-IN-CACHE-KEYS");
sfContext::switchTo('backend');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is no "clean" way to do the job, as different apps are treated as quite separated environments in symfony.
Obviously the job may be done in a less or more dirty way, choose your way to remove any file in the cache/ dir, run the phing task **clear-cache (cc)** etc ...

you can simply run rm -rf cache/*, but you could break some client request.
The simpler thing could be to run **symfony cc** via [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) or [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can create instance of sfTask and run it like this (in sf 1.2):

```
    $task = new sfCacheClearTask(sfContext::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher(), new sfFormatter());

    $arguments = array();

    // type can be one of: i18n, routing, template, module, config
    $options = array(
        'frontend'  => 'app',
        'routing'   => 'type', 
        'prod'      => 'env',
    );

    $task->run($arguments, $options);
```

For all possible arguments and options see source code of appropriate sfTask...