# Symfony1.4 : Clearing cache across applications with internal URI

Tags: php, caching, symfony-1.4

From the [documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/book/1_2/fr/12-caching) (by the way, where is the 1.4 version?!), I've tried this code to delete a frontend cache page, from the backend app:

```
$frontend_cache_dir = sfConfig::get('sf_cache_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'frontend'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.sfConfig::get('sf_environment').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'template';
$cache = new sfFileCache(array('cache_dir' => $frontend_cache_dir));
$cache->removePattern($uri);
```

It does nothing. So I've dug in the [source code](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/cache/sfFileCache.class.php), and here is the `removePattern` function :

```
public function removePattern($pattern)
{
  if (false !== strpos($pattern, '**'))
  {
    $pattern = str_replace(sfCache::SEPARATOR, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pattern).self::EXTENSION;

    $regexp = self::patternToRegexp($pattern);
    $paths = array();
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->getOption('cache_dir'))) as $path)
    {
      if (preg_match($regexp, str_replace($this->getOption('cache_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '', $path)))
      {
        $paths[] = $path;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $paths = glob($this->getOption('cache_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace(sfCache::SEPARATOR, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $pattern).self::EXTENSION);
  }

  foreach ($paths as $path)
  {
    if (is_dir($path))
    {
      sfToolkit::clearDirectory($path);
    }
    else
    {
      @unlink($path);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, it can't work, because it does not generate a cache key, like the `remove` function of the cache manager does.

The `$path` variable should be something like this : `/home/.../cache/frontend/dev/template/localhost/all/module/action/key1/value1/key2/value2.cache`

And I ended up with this : `/home/.../cache/frontend/dev/template/module/action?key1=value1&key2=value2.cache`

This `$path` variable does not include the hostname and the vary headers.
Moreover, all the parameters (`key1=value1&key2=value2`) are not converted into `/key1/value1/key2/value2`

How can I solve this problem without hacking the Symfony's core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this switching contexts. The documentation is definitly wrong.

```
sfContext::switchTo('frontend');
sfContext::getInstance()->getViewCacheManager()->remove($uri);
sfContext::switchTo('backend');
```

Thanks to [jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460828/1408100)